# docker: building opencv with cuda image size too big (22.4 GB)

Tags: python, docker, opencv, ubuntu

After countless errors i have been able to build an image of opencv with cuda for python. But image size is way too big. I have tried to reduce the size by following some articles but failed to do so. Here's one that i followed: https://medium.com/@saiprasanth2007/how-did-i-slim-down-the-docker-image-by-70-of-its-original-size-3099458ed7aa

My Dockerfile below:

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:10.0-cudnn7-devel-ubuntu18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get upgrade -y

RUN apt install -y software-properties-common build-essential cmake pkg-config unzip yasm git checkinstall nano

RUN echo "deb http://ftp.fau.de/trinity/trinity-builddeps-r14.0.0/ubuntu/ bionic main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list && \ 
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.quickbuild.io --recv-keys F5CFC95C && apt-get update

RUN apt install -y libjpeg-dev libpng-dev libtiff-dev libjasper-dev libavcodec-dev \ 
libavformat-dev libswscale-dev libavresample-dev libgstreamer1.0-dev \ 
libgstreamer-plugins-base1.0-dev libxvidcore-dev x264 libx264-dev libfaac-dev \ 
libmp3lame-dev libtheora-dev libfaac-dev libmp3lame-dev libvorbis-dev \ 
libopencore-amrnb-dev libopencore-amrwb-dev wget

RUN apt-get install -y libdc1394-22 libdc1394-22-dev libxine2-dev libv4l-dev v4l-utils && \ 
cd /usr/include/linux && ln -s -f ../libv4l1-videodev.h videodev.h && \ 
cd ~ && apt-get install -y libgtk-3-dev

RUN apt-get install -y python3-dev python3-pip && pip3 install -U pip numpy flake8 && \ 
apt install -y python3-testresources

RUN apt-get install -y libtbb-dev libprotobuf-dev protobuf-compiler \ 
libgoogle-glog-dev libgflags-dev libgphoto2-dev libeigen3-dev libhdf5-dev doxygen

RUN wget -O ~/opencv.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.1.0.zip && \ 
wget -O ~/opencv_contrib.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/4.1.0.zip && \ 
unzip ~/opencv.zip -d ~/ && unzip ~/opencv_contrib.zip -d ~/

RUN pip install virtualenv virtualenvwrapper && rm -rf ~/.cache/pip

RUN /bin/bash -c "export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs && export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 && \ 
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh && mkvirtualenv cv -p python3 && \
    pip install numpy && \
    cd ~/opencv-4.1.0 && mkdir build && cd build && \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
        -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
        -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
        -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
        -D WITH_TBB=ON \
        -D WITH_CUDA=ON \
        -D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=OFF \
        -D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
        -D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
        -D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
        -D WITH_V4L=ON \
        -D WITH_QT=OFF \
        -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
        -D WITH_GSTREAMER=ON \
        -D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
        -D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv.pc \
        -D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
        -D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_contrib-4.1.0/modules \
        #-D PYTHON_EXECUTABLE=~/.virtualenvs/cv/bin/python \
        #-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .. \

         && make -j12 && make install"

RUN /bin/bash -c 'echo "/usr/local/lib" >> /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf'
RUN ldconfig
RUN cp -r ~/.virtualenvs/cv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/cv2 /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages && \ 
cd ~ && rm -rf * && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN apt-get autoremove
```

Running a disk analyzer after `docker run` shows a total of 5GB disk usage. I cannot figure out why the image is so huge. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tackled the problem by merging all the RUN command into one with a lot of '&& \'.
This helped me get the image size down to 5.2 GB.